# Use SAML Token to Auth with OAuth

Tags: oauth, saml, keycloak

Just started POCing KeyCloak to hook up LDAP for user federation (really easy!) and set up a SAML Service Provider with Node.JS (took a bit more time to get the config right). See [POC](https://github.com/gregberns)

Question:

Using KeyCloak as the sole Identity Provider, is it possible to set up a 3rd party service (Appian) as a SAML Service Provider, and use the SAML Username and/or Token(session_index) it receives to request an OAuth Token?

Preferably the 3rd party (trusted) service, behind the scenes, would make the OAuth request (with a client id?) to get an access token, and use the token to make API calls.

Seems like there could be two KeyCloak clients, one for SAML, one for OAuth, but then KeyCloak would be able to coordinate the auth under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange a SAML assertion (NOT its decoded contents) for an oAuth access token. This flow is described in [RFC 7522](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7522) (SAML 2.0 Profile for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants). In practice, this is an exotic use case and it's hard to implement. It assumes that the requester (client) has a way to acquire a SAML response from the IdP and wield it to grab an oAuth access token. To top it off, there are precious few IdPs that support RFC 7522 exchange. At the moment, Keycloak does not support it.

A more straightforward variation of the use case you're thinking about is an ability of a client to request *any* token (SAML, oAuth, ...) from an identity provider/authorization service without reauthenticating. This is possible with some providers but these mechanisms are proprietary to each provider. For example, Salesforce Identity service allows various tokens to be obtained if you send a request with a Salesforce session ID in a specific format.